# Starting an application/service on phone startup android (the correct way)

Tags: java, android, service, boot

I saw some other posts about how to start your application on phone start but it might be annoying for the user to see the application pop up each time. What I would rather do is start a service and check to see if I should start up and keep the app up or shut it down. My question is how can I accomplish something like this or the "correct" way to do it i.e. is it better to start a service or the app?

Comment: Starting a service/app at boot time is simple-  register a BOOT_COMPLETE receiver, and make sure you ask for that permission.  It should start the service/activity of your choice.  The question here is-  when do you want to start the app and when do you not?  That part of the question can't be answered, we don't know why you'd sometimes want to show it and sometimes not.

Comment: I want to start the app to see if it was enabled previously. If it was enabled previously then i want the app to stay up, otherwise shutdown.

Comment: Ok, then when the app is enabled, write that to a shared perference.  Use the boot_complete receiver as I mentioned earlier.  In the receiver, check the value of the setting.  If its on, then start the activity.  Otherwise don't.

Comment: I'll give you answer credit if you can write a little more detail in an answer. (i don't know what a shared preference is nor how to do the things you said specifically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest, add the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Make a BroadcastReceiver. Add it to your manifest so that it receives the BOOT_COMPLETED action.

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.name.BootCompletedReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In your app, you would save the user's preference in SharedPreferences. If you aren't using a typical preference screen, you can always do this:

```
// if inside an activity or service, context can be "this"
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("start_at_boot", true).commit();
```

In your receiver, you can check this preference and decide what to do from there.

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        boolean startAtBoot = prefs.getBoolean("start_at_boot", false) {
        if (startAtBoot) {
            // do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Could you clarify exactly what the SharedPrefrences are and what is the point of them here?